# I want to use the listener () in win32 but the win32 action stops

Tags: winapi

I want to use the listener (on_press=handlePress,on_release=handleRelease) in win32 but the win32 action stops.
If there is no listener, it will operate normally.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key

def handlePress(key):
    print('Press: {}'.format(key))

def handleRelease(key):
    print('Released: {}'.format(key))

    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

def wndProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam):
    
    l = Listener(on_press=handlePress,on_release=handleRelease)
    l.start()
    l.join()
    
    if message == win32con.WM_PAINT:
       ........
```

Comment: used user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hooked) to solve this problem

Comment: You can post an answer to end this thread.

Answer (score 0):

`l.join()` will block the message loop(wndProc).

The listener callbacks are invoked directly from an operating thread on some platforms, notably Windows.

This means that long running procedures and blocking operations should not be invoked from the callback, as this risks freezing input for all processes.

**A possible workaround is to just dispatch incoming messages to a queue, and let a separate thread handle them.**

Comment: @SeungKyu Yu Hi, if the answer is useful to you, don't forget to mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)